# Rendering a new component by adding data to Formik values object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a speed dial's icon that, when clicked, should add an accordion item to the accordion list.

Its `onClick` attribute calls a `handleClick` function that currently adds an object to `formik.values`.

The object is added to the values map as expected but the user needs to refresh the screen in order to see the new accordion item.

I guess I'm not properly handling the change of state in the form.

I know formik exposes the `handleChange` method but I'm not sure if and how it should be used in this scenario.

```
function AddSpeedDial({formik}) {

    const dialActions = [
        {
            icon: <DinnerDiningIcon />,
            name: 'New Dish',
            handleClick: () => {
                const dishCardsLength = Object.keys(formik.values.dishCards).length;
                formik.values.dishCards[dishCardsLength+1] = {
                    dishName: ''
                }
            }
        }
    ];

    return (
        <Box>
            <SpeedDial>
                {dialActions.map((action) => (
                    <SpeedDialAction
                        key={action.name}
                        icon={action.icon}
                        tooltipTitle={action.name}
                        onClick={action.handleClick}
                    />
                ))}
            </SpeedDial>
        </Box>
    );
}
```